# ReactJS - REDUX - state display does not update

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building an app with Redux, and I have this issue:  The state of my reducer is updated when I add elements to it, but the display stays the same.

Here is the code for my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { displayList } from '../actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class ListDisplayer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
   render() {
     return (
           <div className="container">
            <form>
              <div className="field is-grouped">
                <div className="control">
                  <button className="button is-primary" 
                      onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault();this.props.dispatch(displayList())}}>
                      Display
                  </button><br/>
                  List
                  {
                      this.props.list.map((item,index) => 
                            <p key={index}>{item}</p>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
     )
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        list: state.displayReducer,
      };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(displayList, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListDisplayer);
```

To test if the problem comes from the reducer, I initialize it this way :

```
import * as actionType from '../actions/ActionType';

const displayReducer = (state = ['haha','haha','haha'], action) => {
  let newState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.DISPLAY_LIST:
        let newarr = state;
        newarr.push(action.payload);
        console.log(newarr);
      return newState = newarr;

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default displayReducer;
```

And when I launch the app, the map from my component is correctly done and I see:[image]

However, when I click the Display button, and the displayList() function is executed(see component code), as shown in the console, the state of the reducer updates :

[image]

BUT, there still only three 'haha' on the screen, which means that my mapStateToProps does not work correctly, or I do not update the state correctly in the reducer. I have already seen similar errors on this website and GitHub but none of the solutions work for me.

Comment: You're not passing mapDispatchToProps to the connect function. How do you get it to call your action? And how does it looks like your whole state? If you can create a JSFiddle or smth similar, I can try to help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from 'Redux' documentation

> **Why isn't my component re-rendering, or my mapStateToProps running?**
>   Accidentally mutating or modifying your state directly is by far the
>   most common reason why components do not re-render after an action has
>   been dispatched

For more info please visit the [website](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-isn't-my-component-re-rendering-or-my-mapstatetoprops-running)

So basically, the following code snippet

```
    let newarr = state;
    newarr.push(action.payload);
    console.log(newarr);
```

Mutates the original state itself

Why? Because

1) Array.push() method mutates the original array (and also return the length of new array)

2) In Javascript, when a variable refers to an object (including arrays), the "value" is a reference to the object.That means, whenever you do newarr.push(newItem), if you console log (state) you can see that, the very same item is also included to the state itself. But it shouldn't be the case.

In order to prevent accidental mutation, you should do the following,

`let newarr = [...state, action.payload]`

With spread operator, you can utilize the values inside of state array, and after the comma, you also introduce a new value which will be added as  a new item.

Thanks to this way, you don't have to use `newarr.push()` method and mutate the array, rather, create a new array, copy the old state's values and introduce the new value during this copy process

So to sum up, can you try updating your code like that

```
const displayReducer = (state = ['haha','haha','haha'], action) => {
  let newState; // you don't need this, you can get delete this line
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.DISPLAY_LIST:
        return [...state, action.payload] // return a new array that copies the original state's values and introduces a new value during this process

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Props to you Sir for this top notch explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Your `reducer` must be a pure function, so don't use `push` method in there.

```
    case actionType.DISPLAY_LIST:
     return [...state, ...action.payload]
```